# Access VBA Form Data to Table

Tags: mysql

I cant post too much detail due to sensitive info so I will define the problem as seen below.

I have:

**Table1** = read only table containing uID & other employee info

**Table2** = new table created from form, using a combination of Table1 data and user input data

**QueryTable1** = Query pulling relevant data from Table1 such as employees in particular department

**FormA** = form reading QueryTable1 to allow user to select their user id "uID"

**uID** = employee number and a field on Table1, Table2 and combobox on form

I am currently getting **uID** from **QueryTable1** and populating results as options in **FormA** combo box. When I select a **uID** from the list, it pulls all data and displays to the user properly and unique to that **uID**. When I click **Save Record** it saves the **FormA** data to **Table2**. This works, however my issue is that the data populating **Table1** is not the same data displayed on **FormA**, it is populating the same **uID** no matter what is selected and displayed in the **FormA**. The **uID** being populated in **Table2** appears to be the lowest **uID** and whatever is messing up is therefore returning results based on Ascending Query.

I can't figure out how to resolve this. Selecting a control source on **FormA** and setting it to **uID** results in the value being unselectable on the combo box. Other than being unselectable, all values in the combobox appear the same as when it has no control source. Again this combo box is being populated by **QueryTable1** data.

Here is my code sending data from **FormA** to **Table2**:

```
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO [TABLE2] (uID, a, b, c) VALUES(" & Me.uID & ", " & Me.a & ", " & Me.b & " , " & Me.c & ")"
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert
```

Final example of my steps:

> 1. in FormA I select my combo box and see uID values: apple, orange, pineapple
> 2. I select pineapple, all other fields on the form populate correctly related to pineapple
> 3. I click save and the code above executes
> 4. I then refresh Table2, the value populated in uID field = apple and it should have been pineapple

Thank you for any help and I am sorry I cant post more specific info/screenshots.

Comment: when you select pineapple, what query runs? thinking `Me.uID` might not be what you expect it to be...

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question on accident right after posting due to the code editor saying the format was wrong and showing date format which is a hidden column 0 in my combo box, and my uID is column 1. The code below resolved it, but if anyone has a better method I would appreciate your thoughts.

My combo box actually has several columns contained in it because I found that to correctly drive some of the data it populates later on the form. For this reason there are multiple columns visible and invisible in the combo box. I have a suspicion that this is not efficient. But it is working for now and thats ultimately what matters right?

```
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO [TABLE2] (uID, a, b, c) VALUES(" & Me.combouID.Column(1) & ", " & Me.combouID.Column(2) & ", " & Me.combouID.Column(3) & " , " & Me.combouID.Column(4) & ")"
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert
```